# Android - Remove CacheColorHint for ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing Android Application having the `listview` in an `activity`. I implemented the `listview` in an activity. By default, while scrolling the list, the background of the entire list changes to black. So, i had given this parameter: **`android:cacheColorHint = "#000000"`**.

Now while going to the end of the list a white background is showing at the end.

So, here my question is

**How to remove the `cacheColorHint`, showing only the activity's background instead of `color`?**.

Please help me with the Links/SampleCode.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: @ToddDavies yes unfortunately Android has removed all those articles while updating site with news design.

Comment: I don't know what the original link was, but [here's](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/22/why-is-my-list-black-an-android-optimization/) an article by RomainGuy (the Googler who wrote ListView) explaining the mechanism in a bit more detail.

Comment: what happens if you use android:cacheColorHint="@null" instead?

Answer (score 2):

i have done something like this i have no issue

```
<ListView 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/listView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
   android:divider="#00000000"/>
```

try color code **#00000000**

Answer (score 2):

At layout file, use:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
```

and at java code,use

```
listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
android:cacheColorHint="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```